# Solve $-x^2+\sqrt{5}x \le 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Solve: $$-x^2+\sqrt{5}x \le 0.$$

The answer given in my book is $x\in (-\infty; -\sqrt{5}$ $\big]\cup$ $\big[0;+\infty)$.

$-x^2+\sqrt{5}x=x(\sqrt{5}-x)$. So we have $x(\sqrt{5}-x)\le 0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} x \le 0 \\ \sqrt{5}-x \ge 0 \end{cases} \cup \begin{cases} x \ge 0 \\ \sqrt{5}-x \le 0\end{cases}$. I get $x\in (-\infty; 0$$\big]\cup$ $\big[\sqrt{5};+\infty)$.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation are correct. In fact, you can first do: $$x(\sqrt{5}-x)\leq0$$ Using the product law, we can say that the solutions are:$$x\geq\sqrt{5} \; \vee \; x\leq0$$